# Split subsections titles in two columns and including pictures

Tags: sectioning, columns

I would like to make a long subsection title with several parts, one of them should it be split in two columns, and one of those two having got a picture. I've used that code to try it

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection[subsection trimmed to table of contents]{\lipsum[4]
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \lipsum[4]
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]}

\end{document}
```

But it produces something like that

[image]

Obviously my subsection tittle does not pretend to be so long, this is because of lipsum macro. I'm trying to use subsections as exercise statement and sections as chapters of my subject. Thank you so much.

Comment: Well, my subsection titles will not be so long as lipsum text, but they would be so long as usual title. And no, I would like include a figure inside section tile, but with this format. `text \\ text + picture \\ text`

Comment: sorry I deleted previous comment I misread your example. Why have you got all of the text in the _heading_ of the subsection, rather than in the subsection, ie after the heading? Also you do not want the figure environment here as you do not want it to float.

Comment: Really I like to learn about LaTex limits, and as I said, the subsection titles just are exercise/problem statements.

Comment: The problem statement should be the _content_ of the subsection, not its heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a horrible feeling that you are asking for this but it is massive mis-use of the latex sectioning commands:-)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection[some subsection title]{
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\raggedright
this is so wrong\\
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, something like that could be fine, but why do you say what "it is massive mis-use of the latex sectioning commands"?

Comment: @JFernan the argument of `\subsection` is supposed to be a heading not the entire subsection.

Comment: Is there any way to justify the text and push picture to left?

Comment: @JFernan yes just don't use `\raggedright`, for the image I used the spacing you used, each .45 of the width separated by `\hfill` if you made the image `.55\linewidth` then there would be no space at all to its left, or any value in between.

Comment: But that's so strange because right margin seems compromised in comparison with normal subsection title http://imgur.com/a/VMcFk